# Позиционирование элементов (рамка и элемент в ней) на странице

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, позиционирование

Есть рамка, хочу её сделать фоном по центру, и в ней размещать блоки.

Проблема в том, что как только не пробовал, если выстроить относительно неё элементы, то при изменении масштаба страницы, элементы перемещаются за пределы рамки. Если позиционировать их через CSS свойства position, то начинаются проблемы с выравниванием по центру.

Вот рамка (залил её цветом, размеры как у текущей), которую я использую как картинку фона со свойствами

```
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

[image: рамка]

А вот элемент, который я хочу разместить в ней, с отступом от верхнего края рамки, и отцентрованным по ширине рамки.

[image: элемент]

Как его можно разместить внутри рамки, чтобы при прокрутке / изменении масштаба он был привязан к рамке?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.parent {
 background-image: url(bg.png);
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
}

.child{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 left: 10%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<div class="parent">
<div class="child"><img src="logo.png"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Проще сделать рамку, а  не использовать фон-рамку.

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko что Вы имеете в виду? Рамка, это картинка, для примера я просто её залил цветом, какая разница, как она выглядит?

Comment: я имею ввиду что border и background это разные свойства.

Comment: У меня про border вообще речи нет ;) Есть только background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

.parent {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: auto;
}

.block {
width: 886px;
height: 636px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
background-image: url(bg.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.child{
width: 100%;
height: 61px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 50px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<div class="parent">
<div class="block">
<div class="child"><img src="logo.png"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Пока, вроде всё работает, как хотел...

Answer (score 1):

Вот по идее так. По горизонтали и по вертикали выравнивается. Можно дать min-width, и прыгать уже потом от разрешения еще. А так меняйте у .parent ширину, высоту и всегда будет по центру зеленый

```css
.parent{
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border:10px solid blue;
  position: relative;
 }

 .child{
  width: 80%;
  height: 50%;
  background: lime;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 10%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">
  
 </div>
</div>
```

А вот еще 2ой вариант, с использованием flex-box;

У flex-блока его детей - margin:auto; - выравнивает как по горизонтали так и **по вертикали**

```css
.parent{
   display: flex;
width: 50%;
height: 500px;
border:10px solid blue;
}
.child{
width: 20%;
height: 30%;
background: lime;
margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
  
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я наверно не правильно объяснил, смотрите:
`<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.parent {
 background-image: url(bg.png);
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
}

.child{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 left: 10%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<div class="parent">
<div class="child"><img src="logo.png"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>`

Примерно такой у меня каркас.

Comment: @Alexan-Dwer Перенесите это в вопрос